# Edit weight based shipping titles in OpenCart

Tags: php, opencart

I'm using weight based shipping but I don't want the weight information to be displayed in the checkout page. Right now the displayed information is "USA (Weight: 0.00kg)  $24.30", but all I want to be displayed is "USA $24.30".

In controller/checkout/shipping I'm printing the $this->data['shipping_methods'] variable, getting the following array:

```
Array
(
[weight] => Array
    (
        [title] => Weight Based Shipping
        [quote] => Array
            (
                [weight_11] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => weight.weight_11
                        [title] => USA  (Weight: 0.00kg)
                        [cost] => 24.3
                        [tax_class_id] => 0
                        [text] => $24.30
                    )

            )

        [sort_order] => 1
        [error] => 
    )
)
```

What I need is to, for each $this->data['shipping_methods']['weight']['quote'], change the title to a substr to minus 16 characters, in order display only the country info (USA, in this case).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open up file `catalog/model/shipping/weight.php`, find this line:

```
'title'        => $result['name'] . '  (' . $this->language->get('text_weight') . ' ' . $this->weight->format($weight, $this->config->get('config_weight_class_id')) . ')',
```

replace with

```
'title'        => $result['name'],
```

done.

**Best when applied via vQmod extension.**